# HTML Para Alignment

Tags: html, alignment

I would like to align my text below. I need the formatting using HTML only (not CSS becuase the html code is inside a perl file, ok with in-line CSS).Can I do it by using the lines as table rows/columns and specifying the width of table to an y specific value which aligns the text?

Current format

```
September 19, 2014
Status of my report 

This message is being sent regularly to development managers and interested parties to report the   status of having proper headings in the code of products that we are releasing.

For details refer to  Headers page.
```

Desired format:

```
       September 19, 2014
       Status of my report 

       This message is being sent regularly to development managers and 
       interested parties to report the status of having proper headings 
       in the code of products that we are releasing.

       For details refer to  Headers page.
```

Comment: Why no CSS? How else to you expect to style it?

Comment: What you are asking is best suited to CSS (presentation), you can't use any?  Not even inline CSS?

Comment: @Crackertastic : I am fine with inline CSS. Updated. I am using this html inside a perl file, hence the restriction. Can I do it by using the lines as table rows/columns and specifying the width of table?

Comment: In that case, see the answer posted by the user below.  At the same time, please note that inline CSS isn't as optimal compared to an external file.  You should avoid inline CSS as it makes scalability difficult in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any CSS at all, the only way you can position text is by using a `<pre>` tag:

```html
<pre>
           September 19, 2014
           Status of my report 

           This message is being sent regularly to development managers and 
           interested parties to report the status of having proper headings 
           in the code of products that we are releasing.

           For details refer to  Headers page.
</pre>
```

If CSS is allowed, just set a width and margin on the paragraph:

```
<p style="width:400px;margin:0 100px">...
```

Comment: Set only margin-left to the same value: `<table style="margin-left: 100px">`